# angularjs loadModules "should have a dummy test"

Tags: angularjs, jasmine, karma-jasmine, angularjs-module

Running karma unit tests for my project yields:

```
Browser (OS) XYZ section should have a dummy test for XYZ FAILED
    minErr/<@../angular.js:63:12
    loadModules/<@../angular.js:4141:15
    forEach@../angular.js:323:11
    loadModules@../angular.js:4099:5
    createInjector@../angular.js:4025:11
    workFn@../../vendor/angular-mocks/angular-mocks.js:2339:44
```

XYZ.spec:

```
describe('XYZ section', function () {
  beforeEach(module('blah.XYZ'));
  it('should have a dummy test for XYZ', inject(function() {
    expect(true).toBeTruthy();
  }));
});
```

I notice that some states can't be found yet others can...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the output from angular.js (even without minification) is impossible to debug...
therefore angular.js has to be altered to get even partially decent debug output

## angular.js

```
function loadModules(modulesToLoad) {
  [...];
  try {
    [...];
  } catch (e) {
    [...];
    console.log(e);//<<<<<-------- this is needed in order to have
                   //<<<<<-------- any idea as to what is going on
    throw $injectorMinErr([...]);
  }
  [...];
}
```

in this case it yielded:

```
LOG: '[$injector:unpr] Unknown provider: $stateProvider http://errors.angularjs.org/1.3.15/$injector/unpr?p0=%24stateProvider
minErr/<@[... blah blah blah ...]
```

which led me to find `angular.module("blah.XYZ", [...]);` in two different files... I had assumed angular would combine the dependency list of both and maintain a single module reference, however angular will simply read the first dependency list it encounters and ignore the second attempt...